# Prevent spam form

Tags: php

I have a form that sends information to a telegram bot, but recently my form is spammed and they send a lot of spam messages.

```
if (strtoupper($_POST['cp_code']) == strtoupper($_POST['captcha'])){
if (isset($_POST["website"]) && $_POST["website"] == "") {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

This is my code. I even use captcha and put a hidden input in the form and check its value in php.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @j08691 How can I prevent this spam?

Comment: your captcha is no good if the bot can post `foo` and `foo` for both fields, its not checking anything, use a real one like [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use Google Recaputer to verify if the user is a human. Next you can set a session after making an entry in the input field and refresh the page. Here you could aslong the session is set, hide the contact form or even not echo it on the page via PHP. This is also not a 100% protection because the user can delete the session, but hardly no one want to do this 1000 times in a row. Against a DDoS attack you should set up a plugin on the server, I can recommend "fail2ban".